# Unable to mount NFS fileshare to Docker container running on Azure VM

Tags: azure, docker, ubuntu-20.04, nfs, docker-network

We would like to deploy our application which is running in multiple Docker containers to an Azure Virtual Machine. We would like the Docker containers to be able to mount volumes directly from an Azure Files NFS share.

The NFS share is easily mountable to the VM itself, but not to the containers. We tried both CNI and CNM network plugins for Docker (plugin installation and setup were done as suggested on Microsoft/Github documentations), but none of them worked for us.

We always get "connection timed out" or "permission denied" errors.

The only solution we found was running Docker containers with the "--privileged" and "--network=host" options, but it is not a practical nor a secure long term solution based on the security guidlines we found.

We also tried to use blobfuse2 with another storage account and a blob container, but the results were the same. The blob container was mountable to the VM but not to the Docker containers directly unless the "--privileged" and "--network=host" options were set.

Is there anything else we should try/check? Azure Virtual Network setup, Docker setup or maybe something we missed configuring the Azure Files NFS share?

Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Docker 24.0.5

The environment is currently in an early state, so no special network security rule is present, just the Azure defaults.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything else we should try/check? Azure Virtual Network setup.

Necessary firewall rules and network security groups (NSGs) should allow NFS traffic (port 2049) to and from the VM and the Azure Files service.

[image]

- For secure and practical Docker container networking, avoid using `--privileged` and `--network=host` options. Instead, consider using Docker's bridge network mode or custom user-defined networks.

Started the docker container by using this network **`docker run --network mynetwork -d myimage`**

- Specify the `volume-driver` as `azurefile`. This driver is specifically designed to work with Azure Files.

```
docker volume create --driver azurefile \
  -o share=myshare \
  -o username=myusername \
  -o password=mypassword \
  myvolume
```

- If your VM is running SELinux (common on CentOS/RHEL) check that they are not blocking Docker container access to NFS shares. we can also run by AppArmor (common on Ubuntu) but If you see in my below picture It doesn't supports with Image.

[image]

Proper configuration of Azure Files, Virtual Network, Docker networks, and container volume mounts, will be able to secure mount Azure Files NFS shares in Docker containers without resorting to the `--privileged` and `--network=host` options.